# What is the purpose of Arguments in Xcode External Build Tool Configuration?

Tags: xcode, arguments, build-tools

By default, there is a use of `$(ACTION)`. What is the usage of this parameter and field? Is it related to the previous field (the path of the build tool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(ACTION)` refers to the value of the [Xcode build setting named `ACTION`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW45). The typical use is to allow invocations via `xcodebuild`, such as `xcodebuild install`, to trigger a different actions in external build tools invoked from the Xcode project.

Comment: I am not quite understand yet. Am I going to put the arguments of the build tool there?